# how to use the output object in another object in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am fetching the data from csv file in R shiny and when I want to use **credit_salary** object in another output object called **credit_decision**, an **Error: 'credit_salary' not found** appears.How can I use the **credit_salary** output in order to compare the salary with number(e.g 600) in **credit_decision** ?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
ui <- fluidPage(theme=shinytheme("superhero"),
                titlePanel(h1("NON Bank", align="center")),
                tags$br(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Upload the csv file containing customers' data",
                accept = c(
                  "text/csv",
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  ".csv")
      ),
      "Enter the ID of customer",
      textInput("id","","",placeholder = "Enter ID")),

    mainPanel(h3("Data of the customer"),
      tableOutput("contents"),
      textOutput("cutoff"),
      tags$br(),
      "Salary of the customer: ",
      tags$br(),
      uiOutput("sal"),
      tags$br(),
      "Credit score according to customer's salary : ",
      uiOutput("credit_salary"),
      tags$br(),
      "Decision :",
      uiOutput("credit_decision")


    )
  )
)
```

````
  server <- function(input, output) {

    output$myid <- renderText(input$id)
    output$cutoff = renderText({
    paste("Let cutoff = ", 600)
  })

 output$contents <- renderTable({
    req(mydata())

       switch(input$id,
           mydata()[input$id,]
           )
  })

    mydata <- reactive({
    req(input$file1, file.exists(input$file1$datapath))
    read.csv(input$file1$datapath)  
  })

    output$credit_salary <- renderText({
    x <- mydata()[input$id,3]
    y <- 2*x  
  })

    output$credit_decision <- renderText({
    if( credit_salary > 600){ # *****THE PROBLEM IS HERE******
      print("Credit is available")
    }
  })
}
```[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReDNJ.png
````

Comment: Please make your post reproducible by including (1) minimal sample data, and (2) code to reproduce the error (for example, we don't have the `ui` part of your shiny app). `renderText` (which is what `credit_salary` calls) takes the value returned from the function and turns it into a string with `cat`. So I'm not sure what you mean by *"How can I use the credit_salary output "*. The `credit_salary` output is a string (that you probably use somewhere in the `ui` part of your app).

Comment: @MauritsEvers Im sorry for being unclear.Im new in R programming.I just added the ui part of application and the picture via link.How can I change the code in order to compare the **credit_salary**(value returned from function) with any number ?

Comment: This is still not reproducible since you don't provide any sample data. It's not clear what `credit_salary` is supposed to be. As I said, `renderText` returns a string, not a numeric value! Since `mydata` is a reactive expression, why not pull whatever quantity you need directly from `mydata`? So, perhaps replace `credict_salary > 600` with `mydata()[input$id, 3) * 2 > 600`? This is a bit of a guess since we don't have any sample data to work with.

Comment: Thank you very much I solved the problem